# Robocopy batch file not copying when using variables

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

Hi I have the following script that will create a folder with datestamp and try to copy file from source to destination with exluding a folder

I tryied the copy using directlly the path it works but when I'm using variables never worked

any idea

```
@echo off
set "sourcePath = C:\temp\"
set "destinationPath = C:"
set "exlude =test2"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

if not exist "%destinationPath%\%datestamp%" mkdir %destinationPath%\%datestamp%

robocopy %sourcePath% %destinationPath%\%datestamp% /mir /XD %sourcePath%%exlude%
```

Comment: Part of debugging a batch file is to turn echo on or at least echo the variables to the screen so you can see what they look like before you use them to execute another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your variable declarations.  Don't worry, this gets everyone.

```
@echo off
set "sourcePath=C:\temp\"
set "destinationPath=C:"
set "exlude=test2"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

if not exist "%destinationPath%\%datestamp%" mkdir %destinationPath%\%datestamp%

robocopy %sourcePath% %destinationPath%\%datestamp% /mir /XD %sourcePath%%exlude%
```

Comment: Thanks:)  I spent so much time trying to figure out where is my mistake